# What doese 'v' mean in GoogLeNet?

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

In GoogLeNet ([this link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842)), there is 'v' notation in Figure3 like '1X1+1(v)'.
I don't know the meaning of 'v'.

Also, I understood 's' as stride. But, I don't know the reason why plus operation is used in '1x1+1(s)'.

Answer (score 0):

"(V)" only appears in a single Conv block, that term otherwise only appears in AveragePool.

In the text as the following description:

> An average pooling layer with 5×5 filter size and stride 3.

Which implies that "(V)" is also a stride.

Implementations encode the term as a stride.